# How do I make the menu line responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried most things within my knowledge to make the menu line repsonsive with my navigation bar but it won't work. Below is the CSS, HTML and Javascript codes that are relevant..

```js
  (function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
          var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
          if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
            mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
          }
          else {
            mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
            if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
              mainmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
          }
        });

        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "multitoggle"
  });

  $("#cssmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

var foundActive = false, activeElement, linePosition = 0, menuLine = $("#cssmenu #menu-line"), lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

$("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    activeElement = $(this);
    foundActive = true;
  }
});

defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

$("#cssmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
  activeElement = $(this);
  lineWidth = activeElement.width();
  linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
  menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
  menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
}, 
function() {
  menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
  menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
});

});


});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  height: 70px;
  top: -8px;
  border-bottom: 1px #e6e6e6 solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67px;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #5e9682;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9b9797;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #5e9682;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Refine Studios - Subtle Refine</title>


  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <div id="cssmenu">

    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Report</a>
        <li><a href="#">Product</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uczefwaLJmI

Comment: What do you want to happen on e.g. on smaller screens?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:-

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,500,700,700italic);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 1.25em .75em;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/black-Linen.png);
  font: 1.4em 'Exo', sans-serif;
}

nav[role="select"] {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
}
nav[role="select"] > select {
  display: none;
}
nav[role="select"] ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
nav[role="select"] ul > li {
  float: left;
  padding: .55em .45em;
  width: 19%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: rgba(174, 86, 168, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-property: box-shadow, background, color, text-align, padding;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav[role="select"] ul > li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(174, 86, 168, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: .75em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 0 0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
nav[role="select"] ul > li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: inherit;
}

/* small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 44em) {
  body {
    margin: 1em 0;
  }

  nav[role="select"] ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav[role="select"]:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: "Menu";
    right: 0;
    bottom: -1.75em;
    background: rgba(174, 86, 168, 0.4);
    padding: .15em .55em;
  }
  nav[role="select"] select {
    display: block;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .55em .45em;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(174, 86, 168, 0.25);
    font: 1.2em 'Exo', sans-serif;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav role="select">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Stream</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value;">
        <option value="#">Stream</option>
        <option value="#">Lab</option>
        <option value="#">Projects</option>
        <option value="#">About</option>
        <option value="#">Contact</option>
    </select>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using jQuery at all.

Just use the CSS :hover selector like
`#somediv:hover { border-bottom: 2px green solid; }`

Here's a nice responsive flexbox solution that you can maybe borrow a few ideas from..

```css
.flexcanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px !important;
}
#HomeArea:hover,
#AboutArea:hover,
#ProductArea:hover,
#ReportArea:hover,
#ContactArea:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px green solid;
}
.rowParent {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.columnParent {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.rowParent,
.columnParent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.columnParent {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexChild {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
#AboutBar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: 'green';
}
#ContactBar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: 'green';
  height: 20px;
}
#ProductBar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: 'green';
}
#ReportBar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: 'green';
}
#HomeBar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: 'green';
}
.bar {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
}
#MenuFooterContainer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
#HeaderTopContainer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}
#MenuContainer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
/* 

  HERES THE IMPORTANT MEDIA QUERY 


*/

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  height: 70px;
  top: -8px;
  border-bottom: 1px #e6e6e6 solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67px;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #5e9682;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li,
#cssmenu > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9b9797;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #5e9682;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Refine Studios - Subtle Refine</title>


  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



  <div id="cssmenu" class="flexChild columnParent flexcanvas">


    <div id="MenuContainer" class="flexChild columnParent">
      <div id="HeaderTopContainer" class="flexChild"></div>

      <div id="MenuFooterContainer" class="flexChild rowParent">
        <div id="HomeArea" class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div id="HomeLink" class="flexChild">Home</div>

          <div id="HomeBar" class="flexChild bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="ReportArea" class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div id="ReportLink" class="flexChild">Report</div>

          <div id="ReportBar" class="flexChild bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="ProductArea" class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div id="ProductLink" class="flexChild">Product</div>

          <div id="ProductBar" class="flexChild bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="ContactArea" class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div id="ContactLink" class="flexChild">Contact</div>

          <div id="ContactBar" class="flexChild bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="AboutArea" class="flexChild columnParent">
          <div id="AboutLink" class="flexChild">About</div>

          <div id="AboutBar" class="flexChild bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="BodyArea" class="flexChild"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```